# Python how to split a single string in a list, into various strings by splitting it with multiple delimiters

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a program for a calendar and in a specific function, I have to add/delete a calendar event. In my delete_event function, I am taking the already given list of events [date;time+duration] and I essentially need to split each portion of the string in the list. Ex. [2/3/2022;10:00+50] needs to be [2/3/2022, 10:00, 50]. I have already attempted using the re module but it still wouldn't split properly. Here's my code:

```
def delete_event(self,date,time):
        
        '''Delete the event at the specified date and time'''

        event_listt = str(self.event_list)
        for event in event_listt:
            event_list = re.split(', |_|-|!|\+|;', event)
            for event in event_list:
                event_date = event_list[0]
                event_time = event_list[1] 
                
                try:
                    if event_date == date and event_time == time:
                        del event
                        print("Event successfully deleted.")
                except:
                    print("Event was not deleted.")
                    return False
```

Comment: Are these strings always the same pattern? Can you provide some example inputs?

Comment: These are what the inputs will look like: [2/3/2022;10:00+50] or [2/4/2022;11:00+40]                I also attempted at turning it into a string, but since this input is being brought over from another file/program, it has to stay in that format with the brackets

Comment: Are those individual strings with square brackets in them, or are they lists of strings?

Comment: I believe individual strings as for when I print self.event_list, it appears as [2/3/2022;10:00+50]

Comment: I would be tempted to not use regular expressions at all and do it with str.replace() and str.split(). Your delimiters are semicolon and plus sign. You could replace plus sign with semicolon and then split the string: `event_list = event.replace('+', ';').split(';')`. But if you want to stick with regular expressions, I think you can put all of your delimiters in square brackets and it's treated like a list of characters. However, + is a special character and you'll have to escape it with a forward slash: `event_list = re.split('[;\+]', event)`

Comment: @bfris why not add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use named capture groups to create a dictionary for each event from a list of events:

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(?P<date>\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4});(?P<time>\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})\+(?P<duration>\d+)")

events = ["2/3/2022;10:00+50", "2/4/2022;11:00+40"]
event_data = [match.groupdict() for event in events for match in pattern.finditer(event)]
```

Output:

```py
[{'date': '2/3/2022', 'time': '10:00', 'duration': '50'},
 {'date': '2/4/2022', 'time': '11:00', 'duration': '40'}]
```

Note this will also work if the strings have square brackets in them for some reason:

```py
In [4]: events = ["[2/3/2022;10:00+50]", "[2/4/2022;11:00+40]"]

In [5]: [match.groupdict() for event in events for match in pattern.finditer(event)]
Out[5]:
[{'date': '2/3/2022', 'time': '10:00', 'duration': '50'},
 {'date': '2/4/2022', 'time': '11:00', 'duration': '40'}]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not experienced with coding that much. Can you explain it more how it works or is there maybe another, easier way of approaching it?

Comment: The `re` module allows you to use regular expressions in Python. Regular expressions allow you to match specific patterns in data, like phone numbers, or dates, etc. My answer uses a regex (short for regular expression) pattern which *captures* the pieces of information in your strings and stores them in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to not use regular expressions at all and do it with `str.replace()` and `str.split()`. Your delimiters are semicolon (`;`) and plus sign(`+`).

You could replace plus sign with semicolon and then split the string:

```
event_list = event.replace('+', ';').split(';').
```

But if you want to stick with regular expressions, I think you can put all of your delimiters in square brackets and it's treated like a list of characters. However, `+` is a special character and you'll have to escape it with a forward slash:

```
event_list = re.split('[;\+]', event)
```